# knitr does not accept opts_chunk set options for dev

Tags: r, knitr, cairo

The following minimal example does not compile when using knit('%.Rnw')

```
\documentclass[]{article}

%opening
\title{STAT 520 Homework No. 1}
\author{Cheng Jia}

<<setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(dev='cairo_pdf', dev.args=list(family='Lekton'))
options(show.signif.stars=F)
@

\begin{document}

\maketitle
<<test,cache=TRUE,eval=TRUE,echo=FALSE>>=
a<-1
@
This is testing a=\Sexpr{a}.
\end{document}
```

The error message reads:

```
Quitting from lines 18-19 (try.Rnw) 
Error in pdf(NULL, width, height, ...) : unknown family 'Lekton'
Calls: knit ... chunk_device -> dev_new -> do.call -> <Anonymous> -> pdf
```

So it seems that knitr does not accept the device option anymore, hence it's not using the cairo_pdf device but the default pdf device.

Any idea what's going on??

```
System:
Mac Os 10.9.4
R version: R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Knitr version: 1.6

The problem is solved by using the following setup:
System: Windows 7 SP1
R version: 3.1.0
Knitr version: 1.5
```

It seems some incompatibility was introduced when I updated to the latest Knitr and R.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is a known issue and has been [fixed](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/bebf1178e5ebc694f932ddc3556c0d53e44a921f) in the [development version of **knitr**](https://github.com/yihui/knitr#installation), which will be v1.7 on CRAN in the next few weeks (you can install from Github if you want).